# proof by negation - there is no supremum

Tags: calculus

A = { x + 1/x : x > 0 }

How do you prove that there is no supremum for this set?
I think this is the inequality needed:
M - ε > x + 1/x

M - the supremum
How do you keep from this step?

thanks

Comment: For contradicting for a supremum of a set, you can always take the help of natural numbers. Try to show it is unbounded, the non existence of supremum follows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the set
$$A=\{x+1/x:x>0\}$$
has a supremum. Call it $M$. Then,
$$x+\frac{1}{x}\leq M,\quad\forall x>0$$
In particular, take $x=1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{1/n}=\frac{1}{n}+n\leq M$$
$$\Rightarrow n\leq \frac{1}{n}+n\leq M,\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
That is, $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above by $M$. Contradiction.

Comment: WOW. thanks mate!

Comment: It's a pleasure. Good luck in your studies!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the set
$$A=\{x+1/x\mid x>0\}$$
has a supremum. Call it $M$.

Since $x+1/x$ is $2$ when $x=1$, $M$ must be at least $2$. In particular $M$ is positive.

Now consider the case $x=M$. Then $x+1/x = M+1/M$ which is *larger* than $M$ because $1/M$ is positive. But then $M$ wasn't a supremum at all, which is a contradiction.

Comment: that's a great way to prove it, thanks